# If you want to use more than 1 entity using Core Data will you need a managed object context for each?he

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm learning core dada now using the apple guid, and they explain:

"for every object in a persistent store there may be at most one corresponding managed object associated with a given context"

So that means if I have a notes app and i'v created two entities in my datamodel file called "Note" and "NotePad" for instance, while i'm fetching those object from a managed object context I will need 2 different managed object context's like:

noteManagedObjecContext object

notePadManagedObjectContext object

and fetching each to correspond to the matched object?

Thanks

Comment: note and notePad are two different entities, so they can exist in the same context, no need to have a context per entity... Look at Apple sample code, that should help you. By object they mean 'instance', your note 'My note 1' can only have one instance in memory per context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "for every object in a persistent store there may be at most one corresponding managed object associated with a given context"

You misunderstand. It means that for any object in the data store, each managed object context will have only one managed object instance in memory for that object.

It has no relation to the number of entities.

Comment: No, an entity is a *type* of managed object, like a class. Then, you have instances of that entity type (managed object instances).